# how to make a Query with count, distinct, where, Like, Clause in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.connection)
    Dim SQLResult As Object
    Dim SQL As New OleDbCommand
    cn.Open()
    SQL.Connection = cn
    SQL.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT StudentNumber FROM StudentTable)"
    SQLResult = SQL.ExecuteScalar
    MsgBox(SQLResult)

    cn.Close()
```

i want to add this  WHERE Section LIKE '%" + StudentNumberTextBox.Text + "%'

Comment: Hello, where is your question ?

Comment: I see a query, but no question.  Did you have one?

Comment: First, you use method `ExecuteScalar` without brackets - it is wrong, because you need to add brackets (this is the way of calling methods), secondly, this is not even correct function to call it, as you are expecting table in result, not scalar. Moreover, you are prone to SQL injection. Another remark - you don't release your connections - you have to use `Dispose` method on that (SQL) objects.

Comment: It's already there... what is your problem?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn it isn't. Here it is `SQL.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT StudentNumber FROM StudentTable WHERE Section LIKE '%" + StudentNumberTextBox.Text + "%'" AND Section = '%" + StudentNumberIndividualTextBox.Text + "%')"`

Comment: Now you're asking how to add the where clause, after editing the where clause out of the original version of your question?

Comment: I accidently enter it while I'm typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use table adapter

```
SELECT        COUNT(*)
FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT StudentNumber FROM PresentStudentTable
WHERE        (StudentNumber = ?))
```

On form code

```
TableTableAdapter.NameOfQuery(StudentNumberTextBox.Text)
```